# Spring boot relaxed binding not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot. I want to achieve relaxed binding in spring boot. As per this documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding.
It says, even though if we have name with dashes(like first-name) in .properties file, it can be mapped to variable without dashes(like firstName). But it didn't seems to be working.

I have application.properties file like below:

```
person.first-name=orcl
person.address=xyz
```

And my Properties util java file looks like:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="person")
@Component
@PropertySource("file: application.properties")
public class ApplicationPropertiesUtil
{
    private String firstName;
    private String address;

    public String getfirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setfirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getaddress()
    {
        return address;
    }
    public void setaddress(String address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

address property is getting bind properly, but for firstname it is null.

Comment: does setting it to camel case work?  you're not following the reference code as strictly as you should

`firstname` -> `firstName`

Comment: I updated the code, now am using firstName. Still is is not binding

Comment: PropertySource is not necessary if you have the application.properties under src/main/resources. Even if you don't, it's better to use "classpath:application.properties". Lastly, "@Component" is redundant because "@ConfigurationProperties" will already be picked up by springs component scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your setter methods which don't align with java bean standard.

It should be named "setFirstName" with an upper case F.

Comment: glad I could help